# C++ - pthread not executing

Tags: c++

I am implement a Multithreaded Server in C++ (linux). My main aim is to call a function using thread to send client details to other function. Here is my code snippet:

```
while(true)
{

    if((acceptId = accept(sockId,(struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr,(socklen_t *)&address)) == -1)
            perror("Accept:");
    inet_ntop(clientAddr.ss_family,get_ip_address((struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr),ip1, sizeof(ip1));
    clientInfo *cInfo = new clientInfo;
    cInfo->acceptId = acceptId;
    strcpy(cInfo->ip, ip1);
    void *info = cInfo;
    pthread_t thread_request;
    pthread_create(&thread_request,NULL,&Parse::parseRequest_helper,info); // after this while loop is terminating
    //p.parseRequest(info);
    sleep(0);
    cout<<"\nserver: got connection from "<<ip1<<" Port:"<<clientport; // this is not reachable
}
```

// this is helper function for my parseRequest() function using this I am calling my parseRequest Function.

```
static void * Parse::parseRequest_helper(void *c)    
{

         cout<<"Inside Helper"; // Not coming here
     return ((Parse *)c)->parseRequest(c);
}

void * Parse::parseRequest(void *info)
{

    cout<<"Inside Parse Request";     //Not coming here
    clientInfo *cInfo = (struct clientInfo *)info;
        cout<<cInfo->ip;
}
```

If I am not using thread and calling parseRequest directly inside the while loop then everything is fine but when I use thread to call this function it is blocking. Suggestion ??

Comment: Please re-format the code, add 4 blanks before the code to make it code block. Otherwise it looks strange. And you may want to check the return value of pthread_create()

Comment: Should I need to return NULL from the function(the one I am using in thread) .?

Comment: Yes you should, but it does not matter in your problem. My suggestion is to check if pthread_create() create the thread correctly. Btw, you should add blanks for while(true) to make it code block as well:)

Comment: Is this a typo only: You are using &Parse::parseRequest_helper when creating the thread, but your function is defined as parseRequest_helper only - is this a static method defined inside the class? Also, the keyword is "static", not "Static" - is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
static void * Parse::parseRequest_helper(void *c)    
{
     cout<<"Inside Helper"; // Not coming here
     return ((Parse *)c)->parseRequest(c);
}
```

This only makes sense if the `void *` parameter passed to this function is a pointer to a `Parse`.

```
void * Parse::parseRequest(void *info)
{

    cout<<"Inside Parse Request";     //Not coming here
    clientInfo *cInfo = (struct clientInfo *)info;
        cout<<cInfo->ip;
}
```

This only makes sense if the `info` parameter passed to this function is a pointer to a `clientInfo`.

Since it's the same parameter, this code makes no sense. It can either be a pointer to a `Parse` or a pointer to a `clientInfo`, but it can't be both.

```
     cout<<"Inside Helper"; // Not coming here
```

Your conclusion that you aren't getting to that line of code is incorrect. You are. You just can't tell because there's no `endl` so the buffer doesn't get flushed.

Comment: So how should I proceed I understand your point but how should I send structure through thread into the parseRequest_helper function and from there to parseRequest function...any advice..?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion ..I go step by step as you suggested and it worked ..thanks for helping everyone ... :)

Comment: A common pattern is this: 1) Define a structure that contains all the parameters you need to pass to the thread. 2) Allocate a new structure of that type and fill it in. 3) Pass a pointer to the new structure to the thread. 4) When the thread is done with the structure, it should free it. (Unless it contains information the thread needs to give back to the code that called it, in which case it can be reference counted or some other code can delete it after the thread is done with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code have nothing to show us detail of your situation but from your comments I have some points about it:

In line that you say `// after this while loop is terminating`, is your production code same as here or you really terminate your block after it?? Remember when you call `p.parseRequest(info)` you are doing the action in calling thread, so after the line you parsing is done but if you use a thread, after the line (`pthread_create(...)`) the specified thread is possibly not event started, thread scheduled by OS to run in a later time and you should not think parsing is done after it.

In line `// this is not reachable` do you think that the line should not executed? or this is behavior of code in runtime? in any case `pthread_create` return immediately and run job later in a different thread of execution, so in your code you almost immediately call `sleep(0)` and then reach specified line for sure!!

What is the reason of `sleep(0)` is it intended to let thread start or complete?? in any case OS schedule threads based upon internal algorithms so after `sleep(0)`, thread execution may still pending!! If you want to ensure that your thread is started/stopped you must use a synchronization mechanism (for example mutexes) between your thread an main thread

Comment: Yes after the sleep(0) and cout statement I am ending the while loop. I have tried giving sleep some parameters but that aint work. So I guess OS is scheduling my thread for later execution ...so should I go with Mutex ..?

Comment: If you have something that depend on completion of your parse (and your thread as a result) then yes you should use mutexes!!

Comment: I have one more doubt, this thread I am using to collect and store the client information in queue. But simultaneously I need that my main should go back and accept the new request and again give the new client data to this thread. Will this be possible using mutexes ...?? and what if I go with pthread_join approach ..?

Comment: As far as I understand, you receive a request in main and pass it to a new thread to process it, is it correct?? if yes then you don't need to wait for completion of the thread in main thread. Thread should complete its operation and for example send result to the client and possibly close the connection. main should just continue and accept new client requests, that all!! So you don't need to wait for any thing except that you should synchronize access to global resources that will be accessed by more than one thread.

Comment: Yes exactly thread to process the request and main to accept the new connection again ...so how should i proceed further..mutex or pthread_join..as i dont know when this thread will execute by OS.. and I am newbie to threading?

Comment: neither of them, why you need to know a thread ended? all the main do is wait for new request, create a new process thread and pass request to it, isn't it correct?? which point of this algorithm said wait for end of operation? nowhere? so you don't need to wait for end of process!! :)